# Proof of Hardy Integral Inequality in N Dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

This comes from a recent lecture I've had. I have questions about on specific step in the short proof. This inequality is noted as the "Subcritical Hardy Inequality on the Whole Space".

**Statement:** Let $1 \leq p < N$. Then, for all $u \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$:

$(\frac{N - p}{p})^{p} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}} \frac{|u(x)|^{p}}{|x|^{p}} \text{d}x \leq  \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}} |\frac{x}{|x|} \cdot \nabla u|^{p} \text{d}x$

**Start of Proof:** Let $u \in C^{\infty}_{0}.$ We use the equation: $\text{div}(\frac{x}{|x|^{p}}) = \frac{N - p}{|x|^{p}}.$

$|\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}} \frac{|u(x)|^{p}}{|x|^{p}} \text{d}x| = | \ \frac{1}{N-p}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}} \text{div}(\frac{x}{|x|^{p}}) |u(x)|^{p}\text{d}x \ |$

$= | \ \frac{-1}{N-p}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}} \frac{x}{|x|^{p}} p  |u(x)|^{p - 1} \text{sgn}(u(x)) \nabla u \  \text{d}x \ |$

The last equality is the step I do not understand. How do we go from the middle integral to the one on the right hand side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You integrate by parts.
$$
\int (\operatorname{div}v) f=-\int v\cdot\nabla f
$$
for $f\in C^\infty_c$ and $v$ weakly differentiable.

Comment: I see! Thank you